# Setting UIFont Weight

Tags: ios, uifont, uifontdescriptor

In iOS 8 in order to get Helvetica Neue in the thin variation the following code would work

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
```

In iOS 9 the system font changed to San Francisco, so I can no longer do this. I absolutely must use Helvetia in this app and can't figure out how to set the font weight. This is the code I am currently using.

```
    timeSelectedLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: CGFloat(50))
```

I know there is a constructor which accepts a UIFontDescriptor. Not sure how to use that though. Any thoughts are appreciated!

**Note: Before you mark this as duplicate know that the only 2 posts are either unanswered or don't currently work.**

Comment: "I absolutely must use Helvetia in this app" why not download Helvetica Neue font from a font website and define and use it in your app?

Comment: You need to purchase it from the company where as it is already built into the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do was specify the weight after a dash like so.

```
UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: CGFloat(50))
```

Comment: I am using *BebasNeue-Thin* and for some reason, it comes as bold instead of being thin. Any suggestions would greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**, you could simply set this as:

```
textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 10)!
```

There's no need to set the size using the CGFloat parameter.